# Recursion function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have made a recursion function to show navigation scheme in tree form
i am using recursion in codeigniter but this gives error as un-defined function my code is

```
    function parseAndPrintTree($root, $tree) 
      {
       $return = array();
       if(!is_null($tree) && count($tree) > 0) 
         {
          echo 'ul';
           foreach($tree as $child => $parent) 
            {
            if($parent == $root) 
              {

              unset($tree[$child]);
                echo 'li'.$child;
                return  parseAndPrintTree($child, $tree); // Recursion-here(Not called)
                echo 'closing li';
               }
             }
            echo 'closing ul';
          }
        }
```

i passed root and flat array to this function and got undefined behaviour..
what is right way to call function recursively in code-igniter controller
Error::
Fatal error: Call to undefined function parseAndPrintTree()

Comment: Where is the function located?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using this inside a controller or a model the function is a class method, and needs to be called as such, i.e. using `$this->parseAndPrintTree($child,$tree)` :

```
...
if($parent == $root) 
{
 unset($tree[$child]);
 echo 'li'.$child;
      $this->parseAndPrintTree($child, $tree);
      // ^-- inside the recursion
 echo 'closing li';
}
...
```

Otherwise functions, as already said by Valeh, need to be inside helpers. Create an helper, say helpers/site_helper.php:

```
if(!function_exists('parseAndPrinTree')
{
  function parseAndPrintTree($root, $tree)
  {}
}
```

You can now use it with:

```
$this->load->helper('site');
parseAndPrintTree($root,$tree);
```

the exists check is needed to avoid getting a "function already defined" error in case the helper gets called more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution simply i need to use $this instead of just function name

```
    function parseAndPrintTree($root, $tree) 
      {
       $return = array();
       if(!is_null($tree) && count($tree) > 0) 
         {
          echo 'ul';
           foreach($tree as $child => $parent) 
            {
            if($parent == $root) 
              {
```

unset($tree[$child]);
            echo 'li'.$child;
              $this->parseAndPrintTree($child, $tree); // Recursion-here(Now called)
            echo 'closing li';
           }
         }
        echo 'closing ul';
      }
    }